# Why didn't Tony Stark remove the pieces of shrapnel in his chest?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-3

In the movie canon Tony needs the Arc Reactor in order to prevent the shrapnel to kill him...

> But in *Iron Man 3*, he has it removed so easily; why didn't he do it before?

Comment: Yes, but the acepted answer there says something in the lines of "So maybe we really need to believe that the shrapnel can truly not be removed, else Tony will die." and...

Comment: I somehow don't believe the Extremis process hinted at in the movie could be considered "easily" removed. If it is anything like the comic version, Tony as we know him, nearly ceases to exist...

Comment: But Tony didn't had Extremis...

Comment: I think this question need to be reopened, because the old questions accepted answer became in applicable now.